# Rust : How to force a Crate to implement a function from a Crate dependency

Tags: rust

I want to force child crates to implement a function from a parent crate.

The parent crate should not implement the function.

If the child crate(s) does not implement the function, i expect a compile or link error.

Given

A crate "parent", the required function signature

```
pub fn f_parent() -> bool;
```

A crate "child-1", has a Cargo.toml dependency to "parent"

```
///
pub fn f_parent() -> bool
{
    let result = ... some complex code ...

    result
}
```

A crate "child-2", has a Cargo.toml dependency to "parent"

```
///
pub fn f_parent() -> bool
{
    let result = ... some other complex code ...

    result
}
```

How can I do this ?

If possible without using traits ...

br

---

A bit more context :

I want the "parent" crate to be like an API.

I have different implementations for the API, "child-1", "child-2"

I have a "library" crate which should only have a dependency to the "parent" API without a dependency to any of the implementation crates.

The I have a main crate which uses the "library" crate and one of the implementation crate.

I don't want OO, only to link different implementations.

I have seen similar in the "critical-section" crate, but not getting it.

Comment: "How can I do this ?" you can't. That's not how crates work or what they are for. I've no idea what you're thinking of but it's definitely wrong (possibly ML-style modules? the translation of an ML-style module type is very much a trait)

Comment: @prog-fh to me the emphasis on constraining modules sounds a lot more like ML than OO, few OO languages even have first-class modules let alone treat them as full-fledged constrainable objects / types.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to have a bit more context on why you want to do this. What is the parent crate? Is it a game engine, with the child crate being a game using the engine? Is it a plugin host, with the child crate being a plugin? Something else?

Regardless, traits are not a bad start: after all, the parent crate has a signature it expects of the function, which the child crate must implement. This is what traits in their most basic form do, similar to Java interfaces.

Another question is what "forcing the child to implement" the function really means. There is no good way to do this without some additional declaration in the child crate *that* it is actually using the parent crate.

---

Now for a possible solution. The parent crate declares a trait, as well as an "entrypoint", which requires an implementation of that trait:

```rust
pub trait Plugin {
    fn f_parent(self) -> bool;
}

pub fn entrypoint(plugin: impl Plugin) {
    println!("parent invoking plugin: {}", plugin.f_parent());
}
```

And a child crate:

```
use parent::{Plugin, entrypoint};

struct Child;
impl Plugin for Child {
    fn f_parent(self) -> bool {
        return true;
    }
}

fn main() {
    entrypoint(Child);
}
```

---

Reading your updated context, the answer is still similar. In this situation, where you have three crates:

- the library,
- the implementation, and
- the client,

the library crate can define the interface it expects of an implementation using a trait. The client will then have a dependency on both the library and the implementation, and invoke the library's functions by using types defined in the implementation.

Here is an example. The library:

```rust
pub trait Implementation {
    fn do_foo(&self);
    fn do_bar(&self);
}

pub struct Library<T: Implementation>(T)

impl<T: Implementation> Library<T> {
    pub fn init(implementation: T) -> Self {
        Self(implementation)
    }
    pub fn foo(&self) {
        self.0.do_foo();
    }
    pub fn bar(&self) {
        self.0.do_bar();
    }
}
```

The implementation crate(s) define structs which implement the trait:

```rust
use library::Implementation;

pub struct ImplementationA;
impl Implementration for ImplementationA {
    // ...
}
```

And the client chooses an implementation like so:

```rust
use library::Library;
use implementation_a::ImplementationA;

fn main() {
    let lib = Library::init(ImplementationA);
    lib.foo();
}
```

It is the client which chooses the implementation in this setting. You cannot make the compiler or `cargo` raise an error if a crate does *not* define a type implementing the trait. However, the trait implementation itself must be valid, so if there are more functions added to the `Implementation` trait, then the implementation crate must be updated to reflect the new requirements.

Comment: I have tried to add a bit more context.

Comment: "forcing the child to implement" means compile should give an error if a parent functions is not implemented

Comment: @xjnxjn Ok, I added a section to my answer.